# How to get multiple rows of data from mysql through JSON using Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am trying to get the output of my below mentioned php file into my android app through JSON but i am getting only the first entry in my android app.I tried doing the below steps as well i can but i am able to get only first output but rest of the output is Not visible in my app

```
<?php 
    define('HOST','XXXX');
    define('USER','XXXX');
    define('PASS','XXXX');
    define('DB','XXXX'); 
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){ 
        $customerEmail = $_GET['customerEmail']; 
        $sql = "SELECT `amount`, `customerEmail`, `CCAvenueOrder_id` FROM `                 OrderAborted` WHERE customerEmail='".$customerEmail."'"; 
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
        { 
            $result = array();
            array_push($result,array(
                            "customerEmail"=>$res['customerEmail'],
                            "CCAvenueOrder_id"=>$res['CCAvenueOrder_id'],
                            "amount"=>$res['amount']
                            )
            );
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        }
        mysqli_close($con); 
    }
?>
```

JSON code

```
     private void getData() {
    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
     loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Constants.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
               },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     Toast.makeText(OrderHistory.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String name="";
    String address="";
    String vc = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME);
        address = collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_ADDRESS);
        vc = collegeData.getString(Constants.KEY_VC);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice        Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply dont send the data till you have completed the loop and move the array initialisation outside the loop also

```
<?php 
    define('HOST','XXXX');
    define('USER','XXXX');
    define('PASS','XXXX');
    define('DB','XXXX'); 
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){ 
        $customerEmail = $_GET['customerEmail']; 
        $sql = "SELECT `amount`, `customerEmail`, `CCAvenueOrder_id` FROM `OrderAborted` WHERE customerEmail='".$customerEmail."'"; 
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $result = array();
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
        { 
            //$result = array();
            $result[] = array(
                            "customerEmail"=>$res['customerEmail'],
                            "CCAvenueOrder_id"=>$res['CCAvenueOrder_id'],
                            "amount"=>$res['amount']
                            );
            //echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        mysqli_close($con); 
    }
?>
```

You can also simplify the loop as well as you are getting exactly the array you manually build from the resultset, if you use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`

```
<?php 
    define('HOST','XXXX');
    define('USER','XXXX');
    define('PASS','XXXX');
    define('DB','XXXX'); 
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){ 
        $customerEmail = $_GET['customerEmail']; 
        $sql = "SELECT `amount`, `customerEmail`, `CCAvenueOrder_id` FROM `OrderAborted` WHERE customerEmail='".$customerEmail."'"; 
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $result = array();
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
        { 
            $result[] = $res;
            //echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        }

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
        mysqli_close($con); 
    }
?>
```

And even simpify that again if you use `mysqli_fetch_all()`

```
<?php 
    define('HOST','XXXX');
    define('USER','XXXX');
    define('PASS','XXXX');
    define('DB','XXXX'); 
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){ 
        $customerEmail = $_GET['customerEmail']; 
        $sql = "SELECT `amount`, `customerEmail`, `CCAvenueOrder_id` FROM `OrderAborted` WHERE customerEmail='".$customerEmail."'"; 
        $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $result = mysqli_fetch_all($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    }
?>
```

> And to get rid of the SQL Injection vector

```
<?php 
    define('HOST','XXXX');
    define('USER','XXXX');
    define('PASS','XXXX');
    define('DB','XXXX'); 
    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){ 
        //$customerEmail = $_GET['customerEmail']; 

        $sql = "SELECT `amount`, `customerEmail`, `CCAvenueOrder_id` 
                FROM `OrderAborted` 
                WHERE customerEmail=?"; 

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param ($stmt, 's', $_GET['customerEmail']);

        $status = mysqli_execute($stmt);

        $r = mysqli_stmt_get_result ($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_fetch_all($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! for the input it is sending the valid JSON( tested through jsonlint.com) but in the app still i can see single output only :(

Comment: Then there is only one row with `customerEmail='".$customerEmail."'"`

Comment: I checked in DB there are 81 rows

Comment: Sorry my JAVA is a bit rusty. Use the debugger to see what is being returned in the raw JSONString i.e. in `response`

Answer (score 0):

Define `$result = array();` outside of the while loop.